# How to keep LongText field value from getting trimmed?

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, longtext

I have an MS-Access database with two tables, both containing a `LongText` field, `Description`. I want to union these tables and get the result in one dataset. The problem is that `uinon` trims the field values to 255 characters.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Description, LenBefore, Len(Description) AS LenAfter FROM (
  SELECT Description, Len(Description) AS LenBefore FROM References
UNION
  SELECT Description, Len(Description) AS LenBefore FROM KeyWords
)
```

The result:

[image]

The MDB file is in 2002-2003 file format, and I'm running this in MS-Access 2016 64x.

Is there any way that I can get the full text in one single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your query SQL view and change UNION to UNION ALL.

In a UNION the result has to be de-duplicated, which means doing a comparison. Access only allows comparisons up to 255 characters, so trims the field. UNION ALL doesn't need de-duplication so this behaviour doesn't occur.